# Would it make sense to have the Earth Scaled Up?

Tags: internal-consistency, space, humans

I'm thinking of a planet incredibly similar to earth. It's located in a solar system where everything is 1000x bigger than ours.

The sudden turn to this is that humans aren't scaled. The Earth has cats the size of our legs, but on this planet, we're the size of a small unwanted piece of his hair.

We build houses that can sustain us, so we aren't living in houses big enough to hold a thousand people.

To eat, lots of humans come together, hold a seed, plant it over the scale of 2 months and when it creates 5 leaves, they break down the ultra large sprout and split it.

Would it be impractical to live in such places, considering their animals would be wild (no large humans to tame) and could kill hundreds of us at a time on accident.

How could humans adapt on the planet to become normal sized and how could they learn to leave their home planet (note rockets will be small and that a 5cm blade of grass will be 50m tall, so Space could be almost 100,000km away)?

Comment: Most animals and plants as we know them could not exist 1000x times larger then they are now, there are massive scaling law problems.  They would need much larger muscles legs and arms compared to their bodies.  Are we saying that animals and plants have been distorted so they can survive at that size?

Comment: I'm not even sure a rocky planet 1000 times bigger than the earth could even exist without turning into a star, or at least a gas giant.

Comment: A 50m tall "blade of grass" is very similar to a 50m tall tree. I don't understand what you mean by rockets being small: if humans are the same size as on Earth (just everything else is bigger), why would rockets be smaller than on Earth? And why would space be farther from the surface?

Comment: @MontyWild I'm not sure if the poster meant the planet to be 1000x bigger than Earth, just things on the planet (?). A planet 1000x bigger than Earth would have massive gravity and normal-size humans wouldn't be able to survive for any length of time.

Comment: Why do you choose to phrase it as "Everything else in the world is 1000x bigger," rather than "humans are 1000x smaller?"  The difference will be in the way the laws of physics operate.  If humans are small, things like surface tension becomes a big deal for us.  If the world is big, then we're going to get crushed under 1000x gravity.  That gravity is crushing.  It's about half the acceleration of a golfball being hit by a pro player, continuously.

Comment: I tried for a bigger earth-like planet.... http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15062/stumped-how-can-i-get-a-huge-earth-like-planet

Comment: This is a silly question.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: no

Long answer: A rocky world a thousand times the size of Earth would have a billion times the mass.  Feed that into Newton's equation for gravity, and you get a surface acceleration a thousand times that of Earth.  Under such conditions, humans would be reduced to a fine paste in short order.